# Passing private data through a WCF OperationContract method?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

Assume I have a method in my WCF Service implementation called Login and it is defined as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="login/{username}/{password}")]
bool Login(string username, string password);
```

Obviously, passing something like http://localhost:80/login/user1/pass1 is not very secure, so how is the is normally handled in a wcf rest scenario?

Comment: Secure your communication with SSL, e.g. using https:// for your URL's

Comment: @marc_c: This is the Ajax scenario. Calling this value from JS and passing these values in plain text. How do you switch to SSL only for that call? If it was non JS then POST method would have solved the problem in plain Http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other option would be to do some client side encryption, where the user and password are encrypted via javascript, converted to base64, then called the way you have  shown in your code.

This is obviously less safe, because if an attacker knows how you are doing your encryption (by examining your javascript code), then he has a leg up on breaking your encryption.  But this, combined with SSL, might be a viable solution for you depending on the sensitivity of your site.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to run your whole site as SSL.

The other as you mention is to send the user name and password in a POST.

Is there a requirement that is forcing you to do this in JS?

Comment: WCF is sort of new to me. Basically, I need an android app to login to the application by doing http://app.com/user/pass, but I don't want to show the user or pass in plain text at least.  Can you clarify (show example) of what you mean by sending the username and password in a POST?  Does this mean I would have to have two methods, a POST (send user and pass) and a GET (Get value like success login or fail login) or can I retrieve a success and fail message with a POST as well.